# C# LINQ select hierarchy from list where root has a certain property value

Tags: c#, linq

I have a class with the following properties:

- int ID
- int? ParentID
- bool? NeedsShowing

I have a list of these objects, which list represents multiple hierarchies: ID is the key value while ParentID is acting as a foreign key. NeedsShowing is only filled at the root level of each hierarchy, meaning it is only present when `ParentID == null`.

What I need to accomplish - preferably with the simplest possible LINQ - is to select only those hierarchies in the list, where `NeedsShowing == true`  (basically applying a filter).

I have approximately 50,000 objects in the list representing roughly 13,000 hierarchies.

#### Code

```
Public Class FileHierarchy
{
  int ID { get; set; }
  int? ParentID { get; set; }
  bool? NeedsShowing { get; set; }
}
```

List of FileHierarchy class with values:

```
ID     ParentID       NeedsShowing
----------------------------------
1      null           true
2      1              null
3      1              null
4      2              null
5      null           false
6      5              null
7      6              null
8      null           true
9      8              null
```

This means I have three hierarchies with root node ID 1, 5, 8 (where `parent ID == null`). I only want to get all nodes in hierarchies with root ID 1 and 8, because root ID 5 has `NeedsShowing == false`.

Comment: What do you mean when you say "get the hierarchies"?  Do you want a list of all nodes in all of those hierarchies, a list of the roots?

Comment: @Stephen: I tried to get the list of objects where NeedsShowing == true, but it only returned the root objects of each hierarchy. Not mush use there. Somehow I need to build the hiearchies from the list, but I have no idea how.

Comment: Servy: I mean to get all nodes: root node + all sub nodes of the hierarchy tree where the root node has NeedsShowing == true.

Comment: I think you should add the code for your classes, at least their properties, and the List you're trying to run the query against.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
List<FileHierarchy> mylist = GetList();
var selected = mylist.Where(s => s.NeedsShowing.HasValue && s.NeedsShowing.Value);
var children = mylist.Where(c => c.ParentID.HasValue && selected.Select(s => s.ID).Contains(c.ParentID.Value));
var unselected = mylist.Except(selected);
while (children.Any())
{
    unselected = unselected.Except(children);
    var childChild = unselected.Where(c => c.ParentID.HasValue && children.Select(s => s.ID).Contains(c.ParentID.Value));
    selected = selected.Union(children);
    children = childChild;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but this will only show the root nodes and not the entire hierarchy under the root.

Comment: But you don't explain how the hierarchy is related to the root node. Does it have something to do with ParentID? If so it wouldn't be possible as ParentID is null when NeedsShowing is true, hence you have no way to get any hierarchy from that

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear. ID is a unique identifier for each node. ParentID contains the ID of the node directly above it in the hierarchy. ParentID is only null when we talk about the root node, otherwise it contains the ID of the node above.

Comment: I edited my answer to give you the root nodes + the nodes one level below  the root - does your hierarchies contain deeper levels than that?

Comment: Yes, they can go to any depth (there's no limit involved but I've seen 20 deep hierarchies) in our application.

Comment: This seems to be working nicely. I run a few tests to make sure. Thanks a lot for your efforts.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a bit more readable and debuggable and you can tweak the result if you'd like. Maybe faster (haven't compared directly). There's really no way to do it other than recursively or ultra-iteratively like @Zrethreal's answer.  I prefer recursion.

```
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var files = GetFiles();
        var searchableFiles = files.Except(files.Where(f1 => f1.NeedsShowing ?? false && f1.ParentID == null)).ToList()
        var whereNeedShowing = (from f in files
                                where f.NeedsShowing ?? false
                                select new {Root = f, Descendants = FindDescendants(f.ID, searchableFiles) }).ToList();
        Debug.Assert(whereNeedShowing.Count == 2);
    }

    static List<FileHierarchy> FindDescendants(int? parentId, IEnumerable<FileHierarchy> files)
    {
        var children = files.Where(f => f.ParentID == parentId).ToList();
        foreach(var child in children.ToList())
        {
            var newChildren = FindDescendants(child.ID, files.Except(children));
            children.AddRange(newChildren);
        }
        return children;
    }

    static List<FileHierarchy> GetFiles()
    {
        var result = new List<FileHierarchy>();
        for (int i = 1; i <= 9; i++)
        {
            var file = new FileHierarchy()
            {
                ID = i, 
                ParentID = i == 1 || i == 5 || i == 8 ? (int?) null : i - 1, 
                NeedsShowing = i == 1 || i == 8 ? true : (i == 5 ? false : (bool?) null)
            };
            result.Add(file);
            if (i == 3)
            {
                file.ParentID = 1;
            }
            else if (i == 4)
            {
                file.ParentID = 2;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
}

public class FileHierarchy
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int? ParentID { get; set; }
    public bool? NeedsShowing { get; set; }
}
```